# How can I improve the speed of terminal server printing for remote clients?

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

I have some customers accessing a hosted terminal server.  The machine is windows server 2008 and they are using the Easy Print driver.

Trouble is, a 200Kb file spooled size is 24MB.  You can imagine how slow it is for them to be able to print?

Any options to sort this before resorting to some other product, all of which seem to be hugely expensive?

Comment: Doesn't suit your constraints, but we switched to ThinPrint for this exact reason. It spools it client-side, which means that the 200kb file stays as 200kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, I switched to tsprint from terminalworks.  It compresses the file to PDF format before sending to the local computer printer.  I chose that product solely on it working well and the price for me was right.

However, most third party terminal server print solutions will perform better than easyprint at this time in this regard.  Evaluate the options and choose according to the features that you need.

e.g. thinprint,
screwdrivers,
tsprint,
and many others.